# Como executar mais de um comando com espera num arquivo .bat

Tags: cmd, linha-de-comando

Procurei por aqui e não encontrei como fazer isso. Em resumo preciso criar um arquivo `.bat` e executar 3 comandos:

**1.** Abrir um diretório ( `cd` );

**2.** Executar ( `npm i` );

*após a conclusão da tarefa acima*

**3.** Executar um .js em node.

Comment: Com um pouco de pesquisa encontrei o comando `call`, que faz a chamada de outro arquivo `.bat` e *pausa* a execução até a finalização do `.bat` chamado. Os links que encontrei caso queira dar uma olhada: [link1](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option)

Comment: Todos comando executam em ordem até que o anterior seja concluido, ou seja todos esperam, a não ser que o comportamento de um comando especifico seja muito diferente, se colocar todos dentro de um .bat com quebra de linha vão executar em ordem

Comment: Já fez algum teste João Paulo? porque como já foi citado é bem provável que não exista a necessidade de adicionar um comando de espera.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Nos testes que fiz ele parava após o CD, provavelmente pois cometi algum erro de sintaxe. Vou conferir com essas dicas.

Comment: Fiz um teste conforme o que o Thiago Magalhães passou. Meu único problema agora é que a janela está fechando e precisa ficar aberta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um arquivo bat normal com um comando em cada linha. Ao executar o bat ele irá executar os comandos em sequência e irá esperar o comando finalizar para executar o próximo, ou seja, se você colocar o comando npm install, os comandos seguintes só irão ser executados quando a instalação terminar.

Um exemplo de como ficaria o arquivo bat:

`cd usuario
echo %cd%
npm i nodemon
nodemon index.js`

Comment: Após executados os comandos preciso que a janela continue aberta, mas aparentemente está funcionando até esta parte.

Comment: Adicione o comando `pause` no final do arquivo, com isso ele só irá fechar se você apertar alguma tecla.

Comment: Mesmo com o pause a janela está fechando. Na verdade não consigo dizer se ele chega a executar o 3º comando.

Comment: Se um comando falhar, a pausa não irá funcionar. Provavelmente o erro é na instalação que está tentando fazer. Para o pause funcionar nesse caso, coloque o comando `call` antes do comando que você acha que pode estar dando erro. Por exemplo: `call npm i nodemon`.

Comment: Esse call na instalação resolveu e agora está rodando perfeitamente. Obrigado.